# Type mismatch error combining 2 field

Tags: sql, oracle, type-mismatch

I have a case statement where I pull data from 1 of 2 fields FieldB, FieldC based on the value of a FieldA.  The 3 fields are in 3 different tables linked by a unique id.  So my case statements pulls from the correct table based on value of FieldA in Table1

```
Example Data.
Table1.FieldA       Table2.FieldB         Table3.FieldC
Manager             John                  
AccountNumber                             55
BusTier1            Engineering  
BusTier2            QA
BCAccount                                 297
ProgramID                                 11-34.1/2
```

I am trying to get

```
FieldA              Newfield
Manager             John                  
AccountNumber       55
BusTier1            Engineering  
BusTier2            QA
BCAccount           297
ProgramID           11-34.1/2
```

I have tried casting both FieldB and FieldC into Varchar, Nvarchar, Varchar2 and Nvarchar2.  I get one of two errors Type Mismatch or Invalid Number.  It all centers around the ProgramID field.  If I leave this record out I can pull every thing into one column.

Comment: Well, don't you think it would help to show us the SQL you are trying to execute, and all the relevant field's data types?

Answer (score 1):

A CASE Statement has to return the same Datatype for all cases. So just use TO_CHAR(FieldC) to convert the number into a VARCHAR...